# Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+3)}$ be defined on $B_1(1) \setminus \{1\}$ does there exist a function on this domain, $F(z)$ such that $F'(z)=f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+3)}$ be defined on $B_1(1) \setminus \{1\}$ does there exist a function on this domain, $F(z)$ such that $F'(z)=f(z)$?

My thoughts are yes because we can split this using partial fractions which becomes

$$\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{z+3}$$

Where neither function has singularities on $B_1(1) \setminus \{1\}$ but am unsure how to integrate these guys. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: hint: if $f=F'$ you get $\int_{\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}f=0$, Is this the case?

Comment: I wanna say no? @Bongo

Comment: you are right, because (for the example) the local cauchy formula.

Comment: So no such $F(z)$ exists then? @Bongo

Comment: I think that there exists the primitive in the set $B_1(0)$ because every integral on closed curve is zero so the associated  form of $f$ are exact so there exists a primitive function of $f$. I have some doubts for the $f$'s singularity on the boundary (because $f$ isn't continuous on the closure of the domain and i don' t rembember that if you have to have this hypothesis  )

Comment: what about on my domain $B_1(1) \setminus \{1\}$? @Bongo

Comment: for my OP there isn't any primitive.

Comment: @Bongo regarding your hint, shouldn't it be the integral along the radius $1/2$ circle centered at $1$ is nonzero? As this circle lies in my domain

Comment: yes my bad. it should be $\int_{1+\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}f$

Comment: @Bongo does that integral equal $\frac{\pi i}{2}$ since it’s $2\pi i$ times $f(1)$ where $f=1/(z+3)$?